# Training loss not steadily decreasing using TensorFlow Dataset API

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, dataset

I'm using the canned DNNRegressor from tf.estimator to predict the number of visitors to a public park per day given different weather features, and I'm currently having trouble understanding some issues I'm facing using the TensorFlow Dataset API.

The dataset I'm using includes 1200 rows and 6 columns (precipitation, temperature, weekday, season (0 = first year, 1 = second year..), week number, and target label number of visitors). The data is stored using pandas DataFrame.

Before feeding any data into the model, numerical values are scaled using the following code:

```
train = data.sample(frac=0.8,random_state=19)
test = data.drop(train.index)

# Further split to X and y
train_features, train_labels = train, train.pop('count')
test_features, test_labels   = test, test.pop('count')

# Standardize
from sklearn.preprocessing import StandardScaler
x_scaler = StandardScaler()
y_scaler = StandardScaler()

features_to_scale = ['precipitation', 'temperature']

train_features[features_to_scale] = x_scaler.fit_transform(train_features[features_to_scale])
test_features[features_to_scale]  = x_scaler.transform(test_features[features_to_scale])

train_labels = y_scaler.fit_transform(np.array(train_labels).reshape(-1,1))
test_labels  = y_scaler.transform(np.array(test_labels).reshape(-1,1))
```

Next, feature columns are defined

```
weekday = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity('weekday', 8)
weeknum = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity('weeknum', 54)
season = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_identity('season', 4)

feature_columns = [
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('precipitation'),
    tf.feature_column.numeric_column('temperature'),
    tf.feature_column.indicator_column(weekday),
    tf.feature_column.embedding_column(weeknum, 3),
    tf.feature_column.indicator_column(season)
]
```

When training the DNNRegressor using the TensorFlow Dataset API (hereby referred to as *method 1*), the training loss does not steadily decrease. This is the code I'm using to create a Dataset and feed it into my model:

```
def input_fn_train(features, labels, batch_size, epochs):
    # Convert the inputs to a Dataset
    dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((dict(features), labels))

    # Return a batch of (features, labels)
    return (
        dataset
        .shuffle(512)
        .repeat(epochs)
        .batch(batch_size)
        .make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    )

STEPS = 20000
BATCH_SIZE = 1
EPOCHS = 1000

# Build Estimator
model = tf.estimator.DNNRegressor(
    feature_columns=feature_columns,
    hidden_units=[20,10]
)

# Train estimator
model.train(
    input_fn=lambda:input_fn_train(
        train_features,
        train_labels,
        BATCH_SIZE,
        EPOCHS
    ),
    steps=STEPS
)
```

Here is the log output for the first 1101 steps of training. As you can see, the training loss does not steadily decrease. It does not seem like it learns at all.

```
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 1.7277247, step = 1
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 487.874
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.1896706, step = 101 (0.206 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 419.013
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.035381828, step = 201 (0.243 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 478.715
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0111698285, step = 301 (0.210 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 665.781
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.08243248, step = 401 (0.144 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 527.54
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.057627745, step = 501 (0.194 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 497.047
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.047706906, step = 601 (0.197 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 629.148
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.15168391, step = 701 (0.159 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 612.062
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.3931117, step = 801 (0.163 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 455.834
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.19988278, step = 901 (0.219 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 493.121
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.02624654, step = 1001 (0.212 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 454.812
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.187381, step = 1101 (0.212 sec)
...
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 20000: average_loss = 0.121116325, global_step = 20000, loss = 0.121116325
```

[image: Average loss using DNNRegressor with TensorFlow Dataset API]
[image: Loss using DNNRegressor with TensorFlow Dataset API]

However, if I rewrite the `input_fn` to just return a features dict and labels of `tf.constant`, the training loss steadily decreases and the model seems to learn.

```
def input_fn_train(features, labels):
    x = {}
    x['precipitation'] = tf.constant(features.precipitation.values)
    x['temperature'] = tf.constant(features.temperature.values)
    x['weekday'] = tf.constant(features.weekday.values)
    x['weeknum'] = tf.constant(features.weeknum.values)
    x['season'] = tf.constant(features.season.values)

    y = tf.constant(labels)

    return x, y

model.train(
    input_fn=lambda:temp_input_fn(
        train_features,
        train_labels
    ),
    steps=STEPS
)
```

TensorFlow log:

```
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.97960025, step = 1
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 470.174
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.18198118, step = 101 (0.215 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 638.591
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.1380633, step = 201 (0.156 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 652.834
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.11286014, step = 301 (0.155 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 638.016
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.09432771, step = 401 (0.159 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 613.783
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.07982709, step = 501 (0.159 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 614.844
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.0700635, step = 601 (0.162 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 516.951
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.05970519, step = 701 (0.195 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 623.434
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.05116929, step = 801 (0.161 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 512.689
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.044941783, step = 901 (0.193 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 608.299
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.041477665, step = 1001 (0.166 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 390.28
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 0.036976893, step = 1101 (0.283 sec)
...
INFO:tensorflow:Saving dict for global step 20000: average_loss = 0.19528933, global_step = 20000, loss = 0.19528933
```

[image: Average loss when using just dict to feed data]
[image: Loss when using just dict to feed data]

**What am I missing? Why does my model not seem to learn when using the TensorFlow Dataset API (method 1)?**

Comment: Those two functions are not feeding the data the same way. Have you tried with a different batch size?

Comment: I've tried with different batch sizes between [1, 256]. When batch size approaches `train_features.shape[0]`, the training loss seems to decrease consistently. Is this expected behavior?